# Создать правило с AND вместо OR

Tags: email, office, outlook

Пытаюсь создать правило, перемещающее письма, в заголовке которых одновременно содержится `Deployment of Release` и `succeeded` (объединить в одну фразу не могу, поскольку между ними находится номер релиза).

Проблема в том, что правило делает проверку вхождения строк через OR (т. е. хотя бы одна из двух), а мне надо через AND (обе одновременно).

**Как сделать AND или как использовать регулярку в качестве проверяемого шаблона?**

[image: скриншот настройки правила]

[image: скриншот списка слов в правиле]

Comment: Может через  `a and b =  not ( (not a) or (not b) )`

Comment: @nick_n_a, это в какие окна написать надо? Я не вижу места, где бы можно было самому текстом формулировать запрос. Конечно, можно пытаться через исключения выбрасывать что-то, но тогда придётся все варианты, отличные от `succeeded` перечислить :(